# Android Studio/ Android Emulator - Decryption Unsuccessful

Tags: java, android, android-studio, encryption, emulation

I just installed Android Studio, and I am very new with this program.

So when I run the Android Emulator it says: "To Start Android, enter your password", although I have never set a password. 
When I just enter a word with 4 letters it says "The Password you entered is correct, but unfortunately your data is corrupt".

After that, I have to Reset the Phone, but when I do that the same menu with "To Start Android, enter your password" appears.

Maybe it is just an easy mistake, but as I said I am new with this. I also did some research on the internet but I did not find anything useful.

I would be very glad if someone has an answer for this

Comment: Copy from CDROM, still at read only? Just guessing...

Comment: Make sure you are running v26.1.0 of the Android Emulator and revision 12 of the Google Play version of the Emulator System Image for API 24. If there are update on either one of those, create a new image. If those does not work, please send us ( the Android Emulator team) a bug report, but going to: Emulator Tool Bar → Extended Controls → Help → Emulator Help → File a Bug

Comment: I just downloaded and installed Genymotion and it worked!
Nevertheless thanks for your help.